# Water simulation hangs over the surface of the collision object

Tags: rendering, animation, physics, workflow, fluid-simulation

I created a water particles but they seems to hang over the surface, why is this happening?

[image]

---

Still the water hangs over the ground even with Collision Surface Thickness zero:

[image]

Comment: could you upload a link to your file so I can take a closer look?  you can use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: check the "Thickness" of the Effector -> Collision objects.  Set them to 0 or 0.001, as that is the distance BEYOND the mesh that effects the liquid

Answer (score 2):

Your domain is too big, scale it down as much as possible to just cover expected simulation range in a scene. Something like this ...

[image]

You use a lot of colliders with very chaotic topology. I would suggest to use one simple that would be faster in simulation and it prevent from leaking water. *Bake* simulation and for rendering disable this simple collider in *Outliner*.

In this example I used a subdivided *Plane*  with **Shrink Wrap** modifier *> Projection > Z* to quickly recreate your colliders.

[image]

Increase value for "Resolution Divisions" that is too low. 64 is not enough to generate a grid dense enough to bring water closer to collision objects. One division is represented as a cube in domain corner. Amount of divisions is always a longest side of domain divided by this number.

This is your current Domain with Res.Div. 64
[image]

My Domain scaled down with Res.Div. 64
[image]

My Domain scaled down with Res.Div. 128
[image]

My Domain scaled down with Res.Div. 256
[image]

So as you can see each time the Resolution Division is increased, simulation is closer to collider thanks to detailed grid (division) of domain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fluid simulation with a liquid Effector Collision Thickness of 3 vs a Thickness of 0
[image] [image]

and here is a domain where collision distance is too large and particle radius is rather large (2.0):
[image]

In other words, try dropping your collision thickness to '0' and particle radius to < 1.0.

Comment: Karol react to your suggestion by "I tried everything you said, but it didn't work. How can I get over with this? I drop the thickness to 0, then to 0.000001 and nothing...". His post was hidden because was written as answer and not as a comment.

Comment: @vklidu Try a thickness of at least 0.4 or 0.5.

Comment: Karol (author of OP) was asking ... not me :)